# Network Diagram, Word etc

Tags: ms-word, report, diagram

Making a word document of our network set-up.

We have about 7 servers and I need to include screenshots and other info on each.
Is it possible to have a pic of the server that when clicked will open up another word doc that reveals all of the other info. Can this then be mailed to someone easily?

Comment: Im using MS WORD 2010.. I just want to use the image as a link when clicked to contain more info, another doc,  on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should have actually tried to do it in Word before asking. The answer is trivial. For completeness sake:

*Right-click on the image, choose "Hyperlink..." from the menu. Select the document you want from the resulting standard file selection dialog.*

That's it. Doing *ctrl-click* on the pickture will open up the document selected though you will probably get a security warning first.

You can also do it from a VBA macro. First select the desired image and then:

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
    "C:\Users\me\Documents\a-document.doc", SubAddress:=""
```

So you could automate the process of server discovery (or maybe you have the data in a spreadsheet that you could use), adding images and hyperlinks automatically. Probably not worth it for just 7 servers.

I'm not clear what you mean by the last part about emailing. Do you want to email the Master word document or the one opened after clicking on the hyperlink? Either way, Word has a menu option for doing this.

If you are wanting to send the document that is opened from the hyperlink - do you actually need the user to open that document or would you rather email it directly? A simple macro can be written that will ask you for the target email address and send the document directly without having to open it. There are really too many possibilities to write down here - we need more information.